# Erro ao usar php curl certificado ssl

Tags: php

Estou tentando usar o Curl. O problema é que em algumas páginas funciona normalmente, já em outras tenho como saída o seguinte erro:

`SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Aqui está meu código:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.youtube.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Sou iniciante em php e também não entendo muito sobre essa ferramenta Curl, mas qual seria a solução para este erro?

Estou usando Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema é devido a falta de alguns parâmetros necessários ao realizar requisições para página https. O correto seria:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.youtube.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Eu tenho uma classe para manipular curl, pode [vê-la neste link](https://github.com/renatotavares/curl)